# Building Database project in VS 2008

Tags: database, visual-studio, msbuild

I've spent some time with new Database project in VS 2008 and decided to go with it (really cool). But i've also discovered that i cannot build it on our CI-server where .NET SDK only is installed. I tried to put Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamSystem.Data.Tasks.targets to the CI-server but it has too many dependencies on assemblies such as Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamSystem.Data.dll.

Am i right that in order to build it i need VS 2008 Team System installed (unacceptable for CI-server) or there is a simpler solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always need to install on your build server the same software you use to build on a developer machine. In this case, you do need the Data Edition installed. In the same way, if you had web tests as part of your automated test suite, you would need the Test Edition installed.

Comment: I guess i know what to do - putting the project output (*.sql) under source control as the project itself will solve the issue.

Comment: You'll still have to have that edition of Visual Studio if a build is requried in order to produce the project output.

Comment: Yes, but not for those who needs just binaries. Also, as i've noticed, it's impossible to tell VS not to generate stuff like "IF (@@servername != 'SMARK' blabla)" which makes it almost impossible to use the output on different machines. Sad, i hopen than in almost 10 years MS could make something working in the area.

Comment: You might want to ask them about this problem. It's possible there's a simple solution.